# Weight distribution and balance in boxing

Tags: boxing, stance

When you box must your weight be evenly distributed across your boxing stance to have balance or how does it work?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It seems hard to distinguish from [your previous question](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/6002/347).

Comment: Lol, this question is about whether your weight must be evenly distributed across your boxing stance to balanced. The other was similar I guess but about whether your still balanced if you transfer your weight on one leg when you slip, and while that was answered not much depth was given to the topic as it wasn't asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Basic stance, that you learn first in Boxing is with a balanced weight distribution of the legs.

But if you fight, the weight distribution changes and you need to learn punching and defending also in those situations. The weight distribution can also be more towards the front or towards the back foot.

Here is a nice article using the term **axis** to explain  more in detail:
http://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-strategy/counter-punching/the-3-axes-of-boxing